# Laravel Validation of a HTML array within the request

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-blade

I'm using `{!! Form::model( $data) !!}` to get my edit working dynamically, also I have normal inputs like `{!! Form::text('name', null) !!}` but, within my controller, before I send my $data to my view, I use `with` like the following `$data = User::with('Address')->find($id_user);`

When I submit, I send my form to my controller update `public function update(MyRequest $request)` that merge both rules (address and user) to create the validation.

The problem:
The Address input to work with `Form::model`, I had to make it as an array like this `{!! Form::text('Address[zipcode]', null) !!}` and now, my validation doesn't work.

My request looks like this:
`Array ( [_method] => PATCH [_token] => OlF0IuFxwTIucFavzUB9Sk1IGE5NJlaaarbBxSE [name] => Michel [Address] => Array ( [zipcode] => 80000400))`

I was thinking if there is a way to indicate via rule that it should be looked inside the sub-array, something like `Address[zipcode]` but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got that working right after I posted the question....

```
$rules = ['Address.zipcode' => 'required']
```

Instead of quotes like before, using DOT will make you access the sub-array